# Linux flow control exit to terminal on failure

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a query with flow control. I want to exit the script to terminal when the message is: `HOSTNAME NOT ADDED IN /tmp/hosts EXITING`, which is a failure message.

```
if grep -o 'abcdefgh01.was.db.dcbc' /tmp/hosts; then
  echo " HOSTNAME ADDED IN /tmp/hosts"
elif [ $?==1 ]; then
  echo " HOSTNAME NOT ADDED IN /tmp/hosts EXITING"; exit
fi|tee -a /tmp/log;
```

I tried the above script, but it fails to exit on failure. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that, whenever you create a pipe,
the shell puts both sides into separate processes, even if it doesn’t have to. 
In particular, your `if` - `fi` statement block is running in a separate process
from the shell script itself, so your `exit` statement just terminates the `if` block
– at a point where it’s about to end, anyway – so it accomplishes nothing.

There are probably a few ways to fix this – probably some cleaner than the following
– but I don’t have access to a *nix system at the moment to test any of them. 
A simple way that should work is to use a flag file:

```
exit_flag_file="/tmp/my_exit.$$"
rm –f "$exit_flag_file"
if grep -o 'abcdefgh01.was.db.dcbc' /tmp/hosts
then
    echo " HOSTNAME ADDED IN /tmp/hosts"
elif [ $?==1 ]
then
    echo " HOSTNAME NOT ADDED IN /tmp/hosts; EXITING"
    > "$exit_flag_file"
fi | tee -a /tmp/log
if [ -f "$exit_flag_file" ]
then
    exit
fi
```